# Converting PHP code dumped in a custom block into a Proper drupal custom module (drupal 7)

Tags: 7, blocks

Hi here is the code that works when i put it in a custom block as PHP

```
<?php
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#archivetree").accordion({ active: "h3:last" });});', 'inline');

$result = db_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL -18000 SECOND), '%Y%m') AS created_year_month, COUNT(node.nid) AS num_records
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('blog')) ))
GROUP BY created_year_month
ORDER BY created_year_month ASC");


foreach ($result as $record) {

    $created_year_month = $record->created_year_month;
    $num_records = $record->num_records;
    $year =  substr($created_year_month, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($created_year_month, -2, 2);
    $month_name = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );

    $archive_tree[$year][$month] = array(
        'month'            => $month,
        'name'             => $month_name,
        'num_records'      => $num_records,
        'year'             => $year,
    );
}
$i_year = 0;
foreach ($archive_tree as $list_year) {
    if ($i_year == 0){
        $output = "<div id='archivetree'>\n";
        $i_year++;
    }

        $i_month = 0;
        foreach ($list_year as $list_month) {

            if ($i_month == 0){
                $output .= "<h3><a href='#'>";
                $output .= $list_month['year'];
                $output .= "</a></h3>\n";
                $output .= "<ul>\n";
                $i_month++;
            }

            $text = $list_month['name'];
            $text .= " (";
            $text .= $list_month['num_records'];
            $text .= ")";
            $path = "blog/archive/";
            $path .= $list_month['year'];
            $path .= "/";
            $path .= $list_month['month'];
            $link = l($text,$path);
            $output .= "<li>$link</li>\n";          
        }
        $output .= "</ul>\n";

}
        $output .= "</div>\n";
print $output;
?>
```

I am trying to convert it to proper Drupal Block created through a module here is my .module code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Archive Accordion will give you a new block for the blog content type.
 */


 /**
 * Implements hook_help.
 *
 * Displays help and module information.
 *
 * @param path 
 *   Which path of the site we're using to display help
 * @param arg 
 *   Array that holds the current path as returned from arg() function
 */
function archive_accordion_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#archive_accordion":
      return '<p>'.  t("Archive Accordion will give you a new block for the blog content type") .'</p>';
      break;
  }
} 

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function archive_accordion_block_info() {
  $blocks['archive_accordion'] = array(
    'info' => t('Archive Accordion'), //The name that will appear in the block list.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE, //Default
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Custom content function. 
 * 
 * @return 
 *   A result set of the targeted posts.
 */
function archive_accordion_contents(){

  //Later fix Use Database API to retrieve current posts.
  /*
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
    ->condition('status', 1) //Published.
    ->condition('created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC') //Most recent first.
    ->execute(); 
  return $query;  
  */
  $result = db_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL -18000 SECOND), '%Y%m') AS created_year_month, COUNT(node.nid) AS num_records
    FROM 
    {node} node
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('blog')) ))
    GROUP BY created_year_month
    ORDER BY created_year_month ASC");
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 * 
 * Prepares the contents of the block.
 */
function archive_accordion_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch($delta){
    case 'archive_accordion':
      $block['subject'] = t('Archive Accordion');
      if(user_access('access content')){
        //Use our custom function to retrieve data.
        $result = archive_accordion_contents();
        //Array to contain items for the block to render.
        $items = array();
        //Iterate over the resultset and format as links.
        foreach ($result as $record) {

    $created_year_month = $record->created_year_month;
    $num_records = $record->num_records;
    $year =  substr($created_year_month, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($created_year_month, -2, 2);
    $month_name = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );

    $archive_tree[$year][$month] = array(
        'month'            => $month,
        'name'             => $month_name,
        'num_records'      => $num_records,
        'year'             => $year,
    );
}
$i_year = 0;
foreach ($archive_tree as $list_year) {
    if ($i_year == 0){
        $output = "<div id='archivetree'>\n";
        $i_year++;
    }

        $i_month = 0;
        foreach ($list_year as $list_month) {

            if ($i_month == 0){
                $output .= "<h3><a href='#'>";
                $output .= $list_month['year'];
                $output .= "</a></h3>\n";
                $output .= "<ul>\n";
                $i_month++;
            }

            $text = $list_month['name'];
            $text .= " (";
            $text .= $list_month['num_records'];
            $text .= ")";
            $path = "blog/archive/";
            $path .= $list_month['year'];
            $path .= "/";
            $path .= $list_month['month'];
            $link = l($text,$path);
            $output .= "<li>$link</li>\n";          
        }
        $output .= "</ul>\n";

}
        $output .= "</div>\n";

        if (empty($items)) { //No content.
          $block['content'] = t('No posts available.');  
        } 
        else {
          //need to fix to Pass data through theme function.
          $block['content'] = $output;
        }
      }
  }
  return $block;
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#archivetree").accordion({ active: "h3:last" });});', 'inline');
}
```

and i am getting the following errors on my page:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in archive_accordion_block_view() (line 79 of /whatever/sites/all/modules/archive_accordion/archive_accordion.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: archive_tree in archive_accordion_block_view() (line 95 of /whatever/sites/all/modules/archive_accordion/archive_accordion.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in archive_accordion_block_view() (line 95 of /whatever/sites/all/modules/archive_accordion/archive_accordion.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: output in archive_accordion_block_view() (line 126 of /whatever/sites/all/modules/archive_accordion/archive_accordion.module).
```

Any help is really appreciated... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*EDIT* You are not returning any thing from `archive_accordion_contents()`, you just set a variable named `$result`.

Here is the correct code:

```
function archive_accordion_contents(){
   return db_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL
                    node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL -18000 SECOND), '%Y%m') AS created_year_month, COUNT(node.nid) AS num_records
                    FROM 
                    {node} node
                    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('blog')) ))
                    GROUP BY created_year_month
                    ORDER BY created_year_month ASC");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, working now... I want to get it up to drupal.org standard. But this is a start... :) thanks.